# How to translate jsoup to Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, jsoup, j2objc

How to translate **jsoup** to **Objective-C**?
I'm a newbie and much unfamiliar with Java.
Recently I'd like to use jsoup in my iOS project by j2objc, but it seems hard for me.

When I execute

```
cd /path/to/jsoup-master
j2objc -sourcepath ./src/main/java -classpath /Users/wildcat/Downloads/j2objc-0.9.5/lib/javax.inject-1.jar -d ./src/main/ojbc ./src/main/java/org/jsoup/*/*.java
```

There are many packages not found, such as `org.w3c.dom` .
I downloaded these files about `org.w3c.dom` but there are so many packages not found that it's difficult to handle it.
They maybe belong to the standard libs of Java such as javax.net , how could I finished the translation of jsoup? Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.com/), which AFAIK supports the full JRE API. It doesn't generate Objective C, though, but instead compiles Java files directly to .o files (like clang does for C/C++/Obj-C files).